# html link and slider conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use a scroll slider with the mouse or by clicking on image. My problem is that the other links as in the footer or another no longer work. I added "onclick =" window.open (this.href); return false; "but now it's the slide that no longer works when the footer link was clicked.
Appreciate the help

```js
$(function() {
  
    //make functions first

    function showSlide(n) {
        // unbind event listener to prevent retriggering
        $("body").unbind("mousewheel");
        currSlide += n;
        // make sure currslide does not go out of min or max boundaries
        currSlide = currSlide <= 0 ? 0 : currSlide >= $slide.length-1 ? $slide.length-1 : currSlide;
        
        // displacement is window width times current slide number
        var displacment = window.innerWidth*currSlide;
        // translate slides div across to appropriate slide
        $('.slides').css('transform', 'translateX(-'+displacment+'px)');
        // give small delay before rebinding event to prevent retriggering
        setTimeout(function() {
           $("body").bind('mousewheel', mouseEvent);
        }, 800);
        
        // change active class on link
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $($('a')[currSlide]).addClass('active');
        
    }
  
    function mouseEvent(e, delta) {
        // On upwards scroll, show next slide (+1)
        // otherwise on downwards scroll show prev slide (-1)
        showSlide(delta >= 0 ? -1 : 1);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    $('nav a').click(function(e) {
        // When link clicked, find slide it points to
        var newslide = parseInt($(this).attr('href')[1]);
        // find how far it is from current slide
        var diff = newslide - currSlide - 1;
        showSlide(diff); // show that slide
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  
    $(window).resize(function(){
      // Keep current slide to left of window on resize
      var displacment = window.innerWidth*currSlide;
      $('.slides').css('transform', 'translateX(-'+displacment+'px)');
    });
    
    //declare vars then make things happen
    
    var currSlide = 0; //Keeps track of slide
    var $slide = $('.slide'); //all slides
    // give active class to first link
    $($('nav a')[0]).addClass('active');
    //add event listener for mousescroll
    $("body").bind('mousewheel', mouseEvent);
    
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillColour {
  0% {
    color: #fff;
  }
  50% {
    color: #fff;
  }
  100% {
    color: #333;
  }
}
@keyframes fillColour {
  0% {
    color: #fff;
  }
  50% {
    color: #fff;
  }
  100% {
    color: #333;
  }
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  color:#555;
  overflow:hidden;
}

[itemprop="logo"] {
    float:right;
 top:0;
 padding: 20px;
}
[itemprop="description"] {
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding: 20px;
}
[itemprop="name"] {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
[itemprop="faxNumber"] {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    
}
[itemprop="email"] {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    
}
[itemprop="address"] {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
   
}
[itemprop="telephone"] {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
 color:#4a974d;
 text-decoration: overline;
}

div{
 text-align:right;
 }
h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
 text-align:left;
 color:#e7c6c6;
}

#footer {
  
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */ 
   margin-top: 20px;   
}
#footer p {
   color:#555;
   text-align:center;
   font-size: 12px;
}
#footer a{
 color:#555;
 text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #555;   
}
nav {
  
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 0;
  width: 10vw;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
      -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
          justify-content: space-around;
}
nav a, nav a:visited, nav a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
nav a {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  -webkit-transition: color 2s, background 1s;
  transition: color 2s, background 1s;
  padding: 3px;
  
  z-index: 0;
}
nav a.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
nav a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0%;
  width: 0%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #555;
  z-index: -1;
}
nav img { 
    width:120px;
    float: left;}

#nav-thumbnails {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1em 0.8em;
    
}
#nav-thumbnails h3{
    font-size: 1.25em;
 text-align:left;
 color:#764a4a;
 padding:8px;
    
}
/*nav a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: fillColour 0.7s forwards ease-in-out;
          animation: fillColour 0.7s forwards ease-in-out;
}
nav a:hover::before {
  -webkit-animation: fill 0.7s forwards ease-in-out;
          animation: fill 0.7s forwards ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  
  nav { 
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000; 
 position: absolute;
 overflow: scroll;
    }
  nav a {
 padding: 3px;
 }
 nav a.active {
    background: none;
    }
  nav img {
    width: 100%;
    }
  .slides {
 display:none;
 }
  #footer {
    position: inherit;
 }
 [itemprop="logo"] {
    float:right;
 top:0;
 padding: 20px;
 width:120px;
}
}

.slides {
  width: 600vw;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease, -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
}
.slides .slide {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.slides .slide .content {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(24, 20, 20, 0.35);
    /* margin: 35vh 0 0 15vw; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.slides .slide .content p {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2e9e9;
  width: 100%;
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(../img/1.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(../img/2.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(../img/3.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(../img/4.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: url(../img/5.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: url(../img/6.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(7) {
  background-image: url(../img/7.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(8) {
  background-image: url(../img/8.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(9) {
  background-image: url(../img/9.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(10) {
  background-image: url(../img/10.jpg);
}
.slides .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
.slides .slide p {
  color:#fff;
  text-align:left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 .slides .slide .content {
    width: 300px;
 }
 .slides .slide .content p {
    padding: 0; 
    border-bottom: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 
  </head>

  <body>
<main>  

 
<nav>
<header>
<h1>Pepinière Paris</h1>
<!--snippet pour le seo-->      
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfessionalService">
<div itemprop="name">Brewer Digital Marketing</div>
<img itemprop="logo" src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/379486logo.png" alt="logo">
<div itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam eget eros vitae facilisis. Donec mollis turpis eu lorem imperdiet, vel pellentesque nunc tempor.</div>
<div>Phone:
<span itemprop="telephone">303-406-1053</span>
</div>
<div>Fax:
<span itemprop="faxNumber">555-555-5555</span>
</div>
<div>Email:
<span itemprop="email">brad@mail.com</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">1889 Rutherford Ave</span>
P.O. Box: <span itemprop="postOfficeBoxNumber">5555</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Louisville</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">40205</span>
<span itemprop="addressCountry">USA</span>

</div>
</div>
</header>
<!--section de navigation-->   
  <section id="nav-thumbnails">
 <h3>La pépinière</h3>
 <a href="#1"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image1"></a>
    <a href="#2"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="image2"></a>
    <a href="#3"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="image3"></a>
    <a href="#4"><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="image4"></a>
    <a href="#5"><img src="img/5.jpg" alt="image5"></a>
 <a href="#6"><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="image6"></a>
 </section>
  <!--footer-->   
   <div id="footer"><p>Crédit : <a href="https://pixabay.com/"onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">pixabay.com</a></p></div>
</nav>
</main>
<div class="slides">
  <div id="1" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 4</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="5" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 5</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="6" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 6</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
 
  </div>

</div>


    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;" to your code

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is correct, just you need take footer div outside the `<nav>` tag.

```
<nav>
<header>
<h1>Pepinière Paris</h1>
<!--snippet pour le seo-->                      
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfessionalService">
<div itemprop="name">Brewer Digital Marketing</div>
<img itemprop="logo" src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/379486logo.png" alt="logo">
<div itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam eget eros vitae facilisis. Donec mollis turpis eu lorem imperdiet, vel pellentesque nunc tempor.</div>
<div>Phone:
<span itemprop="telephone">303-406-1053</span>
</div>
<div>Fax:
<span itemprop="faxNumber">555-555-5555</span>
</div>
<div>Email:
<span itemprop="email">brad@mail.com</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">1889 Rutherford Ave</span>
P.O. Box: <span itemprop="postOfficeBoxNumber">5555</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Louisville</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">40205</span>
<span itemprop="addressCountry">USA</span>

</div>
</div>
</header>
<!--section de navigation-->   
  <section id="nav-thumbnails">
 <h3>La pépinière</h3>
    <a href="#1"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image1"></a>
    <a href="#2"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="image2"></a>
    <a href="#3"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="image3"></a>
    <a href="#4"><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="image4"></a>
    <a href="#5"><img src="img/5.jpg" alt="image5"></a>
    <a href="#6"><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="image6"></a>
    </section>
  <!--footer-->   

</nav>
 <div id="footer"><p>Credit : <a href="https://pixabay.com/" id="ex_link" target="_blank">pixabay.com</a></p></div>
</main>
<div class="slides">
  <div id="1" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 4</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="5" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 5</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="6" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 6</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank Anisha, I also tested like this, it works well but the footer is displayed year top ...

Comment: yes I also saw the footer issue .I thought that would be manage through  Html team

Comment: Ok I have other solution. keep footer div in <nav> tag . In Jquery section  Change - $(nav a) to $('nav #nav-thumbnails a') every where nav is mention in jquery . Add  #nav-thumbnails after nav

Comment: Wonderful! I just changed  - $(nav a) to $('nav #nav-thumbnails a') and it works perfectly;) thank you very much Anisha ;))

Comment: I did not understand for " Add # nav-thumbnails after nav"

Comment: I have made the changes in jquery .You can take below code.

Answer (score 0):

Add onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;" to your code

```
<a href="https://pixabay.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;">pixabay.com</a>
```

Remove below code

```
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
    // When link clicked, find slide it points to
    var newslide = parseInt($(this).attr('href')[1]);
    // find how far it is from current slide
    var diff = newslide - currSlide - 1;
    showSlide(diff); // show that slide
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Dhaarani, the link works perfectly but the slider stopped working after clic link

Comment: If the rest of the code is in JQuery, it would be more consistent to add an event handler with JQuery rather than `onclick=""` Edit: Nevermind there is already lots of inline JS.

Comment: @ Gwen Thil once click the footer link page will be redirect  to another page. so the slider not show. It's common functionality.

Comment: @Gwen Thil remove this below code in your js. 
    $('nav a').click(function(e) {
        // When link clicked, find slide it points to
        var newslide = parseInt($(this).attr('href')[1]);
        // find how far it is from current slide
        var diff = newslide - currSlide - 1;
        showSlide(diff); // show that slide
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: still the problem of the slide when it returns to the site but the problem is many here ..

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your js file.

```
$('#nav-thumbnails a').click(function(e) { 
    var newslide =    parseInt($(this).attr('href')[1]);
    var diff = newslide - currSlide - 1; showSlide(diff);  
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  
    //make functions first

    function showSlide(n) {
        // unbind event listener to prevent retriggering
        $("body").unbind("mousewheel");
        currSlide += n;
        // make sure currslide does not go out of min or max boundaries
        currSlide = currSlide <= 0 ? 0 : currSlide >= $slide.length-1 ? $slide.length-1 : currSlide;
        
        // displacement is window width times current slide number
        var displacment = window.innerWidth*currSlide;
        // translate slides div across to appropriate slide
        $('.slides').css('transform', 'translateX(-'+displacment+'px)');
        // give small delay before rebinding event to prevent retriggering
        setTimeout(function() {
           $("body").bind('mousewheel', mouseEvent);
        }, 800);
        
        // change active class on link
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $($('a')[currSlide]).addClass('active');
        
    }
    function mouseEvent(e, delta) {
        // On upwards scroll, show next slide (+1)
        // otherwise on downwards scroll show prev slide (-1)
        showSlide(delta >= 0 ? -1 : 1);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  $('#nav-thumbnails a').click(function(e) { var newslide = parseInt($(this).attr('href')[1]);  var diff = newslide - currSlide - 1; showSlide(diff); e.preventDefault(); }); 
  
    $(window).resize(function(){
      // Keep current slide to left of window on resize
      var displacment = window.innerWidth*currSlide;
      $('.slides').css('transform', 'translateX(-'+displacment+'px)');
    });
    
    //declare vars then make things happen
    
    var currSlide = 0; //Keeps track of slide
    var $slide = $('.slide'); //all slides
    // give active class to first link
    $($('nav a')[0]).addClass('active');
    //add event listener for mousescroll
    $("body").bind('mousewheel', mouseEvent);
    
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillColour {
  0% {
    color: #fff;
  }
  50% {
    color: #fff;
  }
  100% {
    color: #333;
  }
}
@keyframes fillColour {
  0% {
    color: #fff;
  }
  50% {
    color: #fff;
  }
  100% {
    color: #333;
  }
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  color:#555;
  overflow:hidden;
}

[itemprop="logo"] {
    float:right;
 top:0;
 padding: 20px;
}
[itemprop="description"] {
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding: 20px;
}
[itemprop="name"] {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
[itemprop="faxNumber"] {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    
}
[itemprop="email"] {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    
}
[itemprop="address"] {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
   
}
[itemprop="telephone"] {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
 color:#4a974d;
 text-decoration: overline;
}

div{
 text-align:right;
 }
h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
 text-align:left;
 color:#e7c6c6;
}

#footer {
  
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */ 
   margin-top: 20px;   
}
#footer p {
   color:#555;
   text-align:center;
   font-size: 12px;
}
#footer a{
 color:#555;
 text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #555;   
}
nav {
  
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 0;
  width: 10vw;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
      -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
          justify-content: space-around;
}
nav a, nav a:visited, nav a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
nav a {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  -webkit-transition: color 2s, background 1s;
  transition: color 2s, background 1s;
  padding: 3px;
  
  z-index: 0;
}
nav a.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
nav a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0%;
  width: 0%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #555;
  z-index: -1;
}
nav img { 
    width:120px;
    float: left;}

#nav-thumbnails {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1em 0.8em;
    
}
#nav-thumbnails h3{
    font-size: 1.25em;
 text-align:left;
 color:#764a4a;
 padding:8px;
    
}
/*nav a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: fillColour 0.7s forwards ease-in-out;
          animation: fillColour 0.7s forwards ease-in-out;
}
nav a:hover::before {
  -webkit-animation: fill 0.7s forwards ease-in-out;
          animation: fill 0.7s forwards ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  
  nav { 
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000; 
 position: absolute;
 overflow: scroll;
    }
  nav a {
 padding: 3px;
 }
 nav a.active {
    background: none;
    }
  nav img {
    width: 100%;
    }
  .slides {
 display:none;
 }
  #footer {
    position: inherit;
 }
 [itemprop="logo"] {
    float:right;
 top:0;
 padding: 20px;
 width:120px;
}
}

.slides {
  width: 600vw;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease, -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
}
.slides .slide {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.slides .slide .content {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(24, 20, 20, 0.35);
    /* margin: 35vh 0 0 15vw; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.slides .slide .content p {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2e9e9;
  width: 100%;
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(../img/1.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(../img/2.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(../img/3.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(../img/4.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: url(../img/5.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: url(../img/6.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(7) {
  background-image: url(../img/7.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(8) {
  background-image: url(../img/8.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(9) {
  background-image: url(../img/9.jpg);
}
.slides .slide:nth-child(10) {
  background-image: url(../img/10.jpg);
}
.slides .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
.slides .slide p {
  color:#fff;
  text-align:left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 .slides .slide .content {
    width: 300px;
 }
 .slides .slide .content p {
    padding: 0; 
    border-bottom: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 
  </head>

  <body>
<main>  

 
<nav>
<header>
<h1>Pepinière Paris</h1>
<!--snippet pour le seo-->      
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfessionalService">
<div itemprop="name">Brewer Digital Marketing</div>
<img itemprop="logo" src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/379486logo.png" alt="logo">
<div itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam eget eros vitae facilisis. Donec mollis turpis eu lorem imperdiet, vel pellentesque nunc tempor.</div>
<div>Phone:
<span itemprop="telephone">303-406-1053</span>
</div>
<div>Fax:
<span itemprop="faxNumber">555-555-5555</span>
</div>
<div>Email:
<span itemprop="email">brad@mail.com</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">1889 Rutherford Ave</span>
P.O. Box: <span itemprop="postOfficeBoxNumber">5555</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Louisville</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">40205</span>
<span itemprop="addressCountry">USA</span>

</div>
</div>
</header>
<!--section de navigation-->   
  <section id="nav-thumbnails">
 <h3>La pépinière</h3>
 <a href="#1"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image1"></a>
    <a href="#2"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="image2"></a>
    <a href="#3"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="image3"></a>
    <a href="#4"><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="image4"></a>
    <a href="#5"><img src="img/5.jpg" alt="image5"></a>
 <a href="#6"><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="image6"></a>
 </section>
  <!--footer-->   
   <div id="footer"><p>Crédit : <a href="https://pixabay.com/"onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;">pixabay.com</a></p></div>
</nav>
</main>
<div class="slides">
  <div id="1" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      < h2>Slide 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 4</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="5" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 5</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="6" class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Slide 6</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, odit nihil tempora tenetur! Fugit reprehenderit saepe impedit at, expedita nemo nulla hic quia placeat ipsum sint, quis unde fugiat tenetur nobis illum. Nemo laboriosam laudantium aliquam illum fugiat incidunt nostrum, corrupti minus optio. Suscipit obcaecati harum voluptates est quod quasi?</p>
    </div>
 
  </div>

</div>


    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $('#nav-thumbnails a').click(function(e) { var newslide = parseInt($(this).attr('href')[1]);  var diff = newslide - currSlide - 1; showSlide(diff); e.preventDefault(); });  add this code to your js file. Now work fine. check it. @ Gwen Thil

Comment: Thank you, I made some changes, I separated the head from the nav tag, now I can also put the link where I want;)
The selection of slides using the scroll does not selects the correct images. I put the site online to show you http://hellotheme.fr/site/horizontal-scroll-jacking/

Comment: @ Gwen Thil It's okay. No problem. you are new to stackoverflow right.

Comment: Thank's..can you help me understand why (since I added an id header) the selection of slides using the scroll does not selects the correct images. I put the site online to show you hellotheme.fr/site/horizontal-scroll-jacking

Comment: may be the same id name in the slider.

Comment: @Gwen Thil select right symbol left side of my answer.

Comment: it's done;) I found the problemit is the fact that itemscope problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the changes in jquery .You can take below code.

$(function() {

```
    //make functions first

    function showSlide(n) {
        // unbind event listener to prevent retriggering
        $("body").unbind("mousewheel");
        currSlide += n;
        // make sure currslide does not go out of min or max boundaries
        currSlide = currSlide <= 0 ? 0 : currSlide >= $slide.length-1 ? $slide.length-1 : currSlide;

        // displacement is window width times current slide number
        var displacment = window.innerWidth*currSlide;
        // translate slides div across to appropriate slide
        $('.slides').css('transform', 'translateX(-'+displacment+'px)');
        // give small delay before rebinding event to prevent retriggering
        setTimeout(function() {
           $("body").bind('mousewheel', mouseEvent);
        }, 800);

        // change active class on link
        $('nav #nav-thumbnails a.active').removeClass('active');
        $($('a')[currSlide]).addClass('active');

    }

    function mouseEvent(e, delta) {
        // On upwards scroll, show next slide (+1)
        // otherwise on downwards scroll show prev slide (-1)
        showSlide(delta >= 0 ? -1 : 1);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('nav #nav-thumbnails a').click(function(e) {
        // When link clicked, find slide it points to
        var newslide = parseInt($(this).attr('href')[1]);
        // find how far it is from current slide
        var diff = newslide - currSlide - 1;
        showSlide(diff); // show that slide
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
      // Keep current slide to left of window on resize
      var displacment = window.innerWidth*currSlide;
      $('.slides').css('transform', 'translateX(-'+displacment+'px)');
    });

    //declare vars then make things happen

    var currSlide = 0; //Keeps track of slide
    var $slide = $('.slide'); //all slides
    // give active class to first link
    $($('nav #nav-thumbnails a')[0]).addClass('active');
    //add event listener for mousescroll
    $("body").bind('mousewheel', mouseEvent);

})
```

Comment: Thank you, it does not work, there is more image selection .. I decided to delete it anyway. It's been four days I'm on so I abandons.
Thank you very much for your help, you are very nice;)